Maven parallel execution
Have some of you used Maven's parallel execution feature with the -T (threads) option in your projects? If so, could you share your experiences regarding its reliability and safety? Specifically, I’m interested in:

Stability: Did you encounter any issues with thread safety, such as race conditions or corrupted build artifacts?
Plugin Compatibility: Were there specific plugins that caused problems or required special attention to work correctly with parallel builds?
Best Practices: What best practices or configurations did you find essential to ensure stable and reliable builds when using parallel execution?
Overall Recommendation: Based on your experience, would you recommend using Maven parallel execution for large projects? Why or why not?

Your insights would be incredibly valuable for those considering this feature to optimize their build processes.
